# Why is Kubernetes service external name not accessible on the internet?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I want to access a PostgreSQL component deployed in Kubernetes on GCP from the internet.

I wrote Pulumi code for a service with an external name.
The service looks like this:

```
import * as k8s from "@pulumi/kubernetes";
import {clusterProvider} from './cluster'
export const postgresService = new k8s.core.v1.Service('postgres-service', {
               metadata: {name: 'postgres'},
               spec: { type: 'ExternalName',
                       externalName: "dev.postgresql.steinko.org",
                       ports: [ {port: 5432 }] ,
                       selector: { app:'postgres'}, 
                     }
           },
          { provider: clusterProvider}
)
```

When I click on the endpoint `dev.postgresql.steinko.org:5432` in the service window in GCP I get the error message:

```
This site can’t be reachedCheck if there is a typo in dev.postgresql.steinko.org.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

**Questions:**

1. What must I do to get access to `dev.postgresql.steinko.org` so that I can get access to database on my computer?
2. Is there another way I can get access to the database ?

Comment: That log error ```DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN```  seems an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/178037957) with the external database DNS.

Answer (score 1):

A Service of type `ExternalName` will not be useful. Its main purpose is to present as native cluster services, **services that are hosted externally**. For example, with an `ExternalName`, you can expose an AWS service as a regular service hosted on GKE. See
https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/network/service-external-name.md

You can create a `LoadBalancer` service instead. GCP will then create an `External LoadBalancer` to expose your service to the internet: see https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/exposing-apps#creating_a_service_of_type_loadbalancer